# How to draw on images with PencilKit in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

## Situation

I have an iOS app in which users can draw lines on images with PencilKit. The way I implemented is that create a canvas on top of an image that a user has chosen, then the canvas and the image are converted into one image.

## Problem

The way it does decreases the resolution of the concatenated image a little bit, and I don't think it isn't the best way to do so.

## What I want

I want something like the `markup` feature which we can use as the default when we edit photos on iOS.
[image]
[image]
[image]

## Questions

- Is it possible to implement the `markup` feature to my app? If so, how would you implement that?
- Is there any better way, github repos, and any tips?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/65124171/12299030?

Comment: @Asperi Thank you for your comment. The way I implemented is pretty similar to the way mentioned in the post you provided. I am curious if there is a way that we can directly edit an image instead of concatenating a background image and a canvas.